# What is your suggestion to write clean and well organized php code?

Tags: php, code-snippets

I am a php beginner coder.

I always find myself in a mess when I try to alter or add something to my scripts. Because they are not well organized.

So, I want to learn how to organize my code, so it becomes easy later on to change it.

Also, there is a lot of code snippets that I use frequently in all of my scripts. Like the database codes. Is there is a way to arrange those snippets?

Comment: Might be better suited as a community wiki, as I doubt there is one "correct" answer.

Comment: Have a look at the MVC pattern. It's pretty useful. Voting to move this to programmers

Comment: Clean and well-organized PHP code is not so different from other languages. The same tensions apply and the language provides similar features that can be used to resolve them.

Comment: You can write clean  and organized PHP code? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn Object-Oriented Programming:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

http://www.zend.com/en/services/training/

http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/oo-php-part-1-oop-in-full-effect

http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/

Comment: I would argue that OOP code isn't any cleaner that procedural code, per say. I've seen OOP code that is messier and less organized than comparable procedural code.

Comment: OOP is way of organizing, not a panacea. That's why I said *learn* and not *do*. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using a [convention-over-configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) framework [(1)](http://cakephp.org/)[(2)](http://www.symfony-project.org/)[(etc)](http://www.google.ca/search?aq=0&oq=convention%20over%20configuration%20ph&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=convention%20over%20configuration%20php) would help you organize your code to a decent extent. They can only do so much for you however, as in the end it is still up to you to do logical things.

The benefit of a convention-over-configuration framework is that it guides you in the right direction by making you do things by a standard convention unless you explicitly override(configure) it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to learn OOP and a template system like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Note : this will make you code well but slowly

Here are some guidelines that may also help:

- Use comments in PHP// # /* */ not HTML.
- Use good variable names to denote what you are using.
- Cut the style as header , nav , right , left , center , footer , others.
- Move styles codes a separate file and just link it.
- Move PHP code to the top of the file and the forms and HTML to the bottom. You you can use PHP with HTML(when required). Ex: you can make your query and row check in the top of the page and merge the loop with HTML.

Comment: Mixing HTML with PHP in a single file is pretty much the definition of "unclean" code.